# Trying to save POST data CLASS NAME in STUDENT model (foreign key)?

Tags: python, django, view, model

**I am trying to displaying classes in a form on a page. when enrol button is clicked i get the class name and assign it to student model (which has a foreign key to the class model)..**

**Update:**

> NEW ERROR: ValueError at /enrol/
>   Cannot assign "'guitar101'": "StudentProfile.student_class" must be a "MusicClass" instance.

- New to django I have no idea what I'm doing, please help! ***My Attempt, what's the issue?***

**models.py**

```
class StudentProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField('Accounts', related_name='student_profile')
    student_class = models.ForeignKey(to=MusicClass, related_name="student_class", null=True, blank=True)
    is_student = models.BooleanField('student status', default=True)
     # more fields


class MusicClass(models.Model):
    class_name = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    # more fields
```

**views.py**

```
# enrolls student
def studentEnrol(request):

    if request.method == "POST":
       musicClass     = request.POST.get('musicClass', '')
       student_profile  = StudentProfile(student_class=musicClass)
       student_profile.save()
       return HttpResponseRedirect('/') 


    else:    
        querySet = MusicClass.objects.all()
        args = {'classes': querySet }

    return render(request, 'accounts/enrol.html', args)
```

**forms.py**

```
class MusicClassesEnrolForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MusicClass
        fields = ('class_name', 'class_level', 'class_time', 'class_room', 'instrument_taught', 'day', 'teacher')
```

**enrol.html**

```
 {% extends 'base.html' %}

 {% block body %}
 <div class="outer"><div class="container">
     <h1> Enrol into Class </h1>

    <table style="width:100%">
      <tr>
        <th>Class Name</th>
        <th>Instrument</th> 
        <th>Class Level</th>
        <th>Time</th>
        <th>Teacher</th>
        <th>Room</th>
        <th>Register</th>
      </tr><br>
        {% for class in classes %}

          <tr>
            <td>{{ class.class_name }}</td>
            <td>{{ class.instrument_taught }}</td>
            <td>{{ class.class_level }}</td>
            <td>{{ class.class_time }}</td>
            <td>{{ class.teacher }}</td>
            <td>{{ class.class_room }}</td>
            <td><form method="post">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <input type="hidden" name="musicClass" value="{{ class.class_name }}">
                <input type="submit" name="enrolBtn" value="Enrol">
            </form></td>
          </tr>

        {% endfor %}
     <table>


    </p>

</div>
</div>
{% include "footer.html" %}
{% endblock %}
```

ideas please?

**UPDATE - TRACE BACK ADDED**

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/enrol/

Django Version: 1.11.7
Python Version: 3.6.5
Installed Applications:
['accounts',
 'timetable',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "C:\Users\N9587268\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  41.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Users\N9587268\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Users\N9587268\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "D:\ifb299\webrepo\musicwebsite\website\accounts\views.py" in studentEnrol
  127.        StudentProfile = StudentProfile(student_class=musicClass)

Exception Type: UnboundLocalError at /enrol/
Exception Value: local variable 'StudentProfile' referenced before assignment
```

**Request information POST (Example this is what i am getting from post when clicking on a enrol btn)**

```
csrfmiddlewaretoken 
'TY28RiLjhtu98v8uthXFuCGJ4pPO3z6e02IDa6x8UFujenzEZdECunhxuqcAKtCw'
musicClass  
'guitar101'
enrolBtn    
'Enrol'
```

Comment: It's just because you do not import `StudentProfile` model before using it here: `StudentProfile(student_class=musicClass)`

Comment: Did you import `StudentProfile` in your `views.py`? Also `StudentProfile = StudentProfile(student_class=musicClass)` does not make sense. You are trying to reassign the class definition. Choose a different variable name, the usual convention is `snake_case`, i.e. `student_profile = StudentProfile(...)`.

Comment: from accounts.models import Accounts, StudentProfile its imported. This line here: StudentProfile(student_class=musicClass)     im not even sure if that is what you do... I'm trying to assign the class_name to the student... can you please give me an example

Comment: so the error is because `StudentProfile` is not present. can you tell us where you add this line `from accounts.models import Accounts, StudentProfile`, is it in the same file as your view?

Comment: okay error gone after changing to snake_case i.e. student_profile.... however new error: Cannot assign "'guitar101'": "StudentProfile.student_class" must be a "MusicClass" instance.  @Selcuk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now you're trying to assign a `string` to a `ForeignKey` field which is incorrect.
after getting `musicClass     = request.POST.get('musicClass', '')`, you should have or create a `MusicClass` instance with it

> I use [get_or_create](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create)

```
# @login_required # A login decorator is very important here
def studentEnrol(request):
    user = request.user
    if not hasattr(user,'student_profile'): 
         # The current user doesn't have student_profile attribute
         # redirect to the page you want
         return redirect('completeProfile') # for instance
    student_profile = request.user.student_profile
    if request.method == "POST":
         id_musicClass     = request.POST.get('musicClass')
         music_class = MusicClass.objects.get(id=id_musicClass)
         # or music_class = get_object_or_404(MusicClass,id=id_musicClass)
         student_profile.student_class = music_class
         student_profile.save()
         return HttpResponseRedirect('/') 
    else:
        '''rest of the codes'''
```

Comment: I see, I've pasted your solution, getting: IntegrityError at /enrol/
(1048, "Column 'user_id' cannot be null")  ideas?

Comment: It might be due to having created an Abstract use which I need to reference, heres is the user model : https://imgur.com/a/rvzslzY

Comment: Just because of this line in your model `class StudentProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField('Accounts', related_name='student_profile')` when creating a StudentProfile, you must assign account as well, with a user instance model

Comment: I updated my answer: if the current user is logged in, then you should assisgn `user` with the current logged in user with `user=request.user` like this `StudentProfile(student_class=music_class,user=request.user)`

Comment: Right, it kinda worked, tested again with another user profile but getting this error:  IntegrityError at /enrol/
(1062, "Duplicate entry '7' for key 'user_id'")

Comment: Why is it creating i.e. MusicClass.objects.get_or_create(class_name=musicClass) I only want to assign

Comment: that might be the issue? because its just creating random id classes

Comment: The error is because, account is set to OneToOne user, so whenever another user tries to have the same instance, this will raise an error. It doesn't make sense that a user can have multiple StudentProfile

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171663/discussion-between-lemayzeur-and-shaz).

Answer (score 0):

The `musicClass` variable contains the *id* of a `MusicClass` object and not the instance itself:

```
musicClass     = request.POST.get('musicClass', '')
student_profile  = StudentProfile(student_class=musicClass)
```

In order to assign it to the `student_class` field you need the instance. Try this:

```
music_class_id = int(request.POST.get('musicClass'))
music_class = MusicClass.objects.get(pk=music_class_id)
student_profile  = StudentProfile(student_class=music_class)
```

and change the following line

```
<input type="hidden" name="musicClass" value="{{ class.class_name }}">
```

to

```
<input type="hidden" name="musicClass" value="{{ class.id }}">
```

Comment: Try `print`ing `music_class_id` and `music_class`. Do they contain any data?